# how to filter only the rows containing first occurrence of an item in Django query

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have below data from my Django model

```
id  Date  value
0   1975     a
21  1975     b
1   1976     b
22  1976     c
3   1977     a
2   1977     b
4   1978     c
25  1978     d
5   1979     e
26  1979     f
6   1980     a
27  1980     f
```

Model

```
class Items(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    value = models.CharField()
```

I am having trouble finding a way to keep only the lines containing the first occurrence of a'value'. I want to drop duplicate 'values', keeping the row with the lowest 'Date'.The end result should be:

```
id   Date value
0   1975     a
21  1975     b
22  1976     c
25  1978     d
5   1979     e
26  1979     f
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Added model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter by eliminating all items for which there is an earlier record:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Items.objects.filter(
    ~Exists(Items.objects.filter(
        Q(date__lt=OuterRef('date')) | Q(Date=OuterRef('date'), pk__lt=OuterRef('pk')),
        value=OuterRef('value')
    ))
)
```

We thus check if there is a record with the same `value` where the `date` is smaller than our current record, or where the date is the same but the primary key is smaller (as tie breaker).

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Items` instead of <s>`Item`</s>.